# I want to restart player if stopped

Tags: android

I am a new Android developer and I made a ShoutCast radio player. It is working good but when I open app it works for a few times but suddenly stops and I need to press stop and play again but i need to handle Android player errors to automatic restart on errors.

```
package com.test.test;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class StreamService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "StreamService";
    MediaPlayer mp;
    boolean isPlaying;
    Intent MainActivity;

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Notification n;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;

    // Change this int to some number specifically for this app
    int notifId = 85;

     private OnAudioFocusChangeListener focusChangeListener =
              new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
                      public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
                        switch (focusChange) {

                               case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK) :
                               // Lower the volume while ducking.
                               mp.setVolume(0.2f, 0.2f);
                               break;
                               case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT) :
                               mp.pause();
                               break;

                               case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) :
                               mp.stop();

                               break;

                               case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) :
                               // Return the volume to normal and resume if paused.
                               mp.setVolume(1f, 1f);
                               mp.start();
                               break;
                               default: break;
    }
    }
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

        // Init the SharedPreferences and Editor
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        editor = prefs.edit();

        // Set up the buffering notification
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        String notifTitle = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        String notifMessage = context.getResources().getString(R.string.buffering);

        n = new Notification();
        n.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        n.tickerText = "Buffering";
        n.when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Intent nIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        nIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, nIntent, 0);

        n.setLatestEventInfo(context, notifTitle, notifMessage, pIntent);

        notificationManager.notify(notifId, n);

        // It's very important that you put the IP/URL of your ShoutCast stream here
        // Otherwise you'll get Webcom Radio
        String url = "http://47.182.19.93:9888/";
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(url);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e(TAG, "SecurityException");
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e(TAG, "IllegalStateException");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException");
        }   
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        mp.start();
        // Set the isPlaying preference to true
        editor.putBoolean("isPlaying", true);
        editor.commit();

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        String notifTitle = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        String notifMessage = context.getResources().getString(R.string.now_playing);

        n.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        n.tickerText = notifMessage;
        n.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        n.when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Intent nIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, nIntent, 0);

        n.setLatestEventInfo(context, notifTitle, notifMessage, pIntent);
        // Change 5315 to some nother number
        notificationManager.notify(notifId, n);





        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        // Request audio focus for playback
        int result = am.requestAudioFocus(focusChangeListener,
        // Use the music stream.
        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
        // Request permanent focus.
        AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);


        if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
        // other app had stopped playing song now , so u can do u stuff now .

        }
            }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
        editor.putBoolean("isPlaying", false);
        editor.commit();
        notificationManager.cancel(notifId);
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        am.abandonAudioFocus(focusChangeListener);


    }

}
```

---

```
08-26 12:00:49.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:00:49.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:00:49.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:00:49.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:00:49.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=5, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:00:49.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): New video size 0 x 0
08-26 12:00:49.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:00:49.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:00:49.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:00:49.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): prepared
08-26 12:00:49.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): signal application thread
08-26 12:00:49.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:00:49.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): prepare complete - status=0
08-26 12:00:49.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:00:49.760: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(4800): start
08-26 12:00:49.760: V/MediaPlayer(4800): start
08-26 12:00:49.775: D/StreamService(4800): onStart
08-26 12:00:49.775: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(4800): start
08-26 12:00:49.775: V/MediaPlayer(4800): start
08-26 12:00:49.890: W/MediaPlayer(4800): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
08-26 12:00:49.890: W/MediaPlayer(4800): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
08-26 12:00:49.890: W/MediaPlayer(4800): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
08-26 12:00:49.890: I/MediaPlayer(4800): Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
08-26 12:00:50.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:00:50.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:00:50.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:00:50.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:00:51.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:00:51.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:00:51.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:00:51.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:00:52.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:00:52.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:00:52.755: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:00:52.760: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:00:53.760: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:00:53.760: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:00:53.760: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:00:53.760: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:00:54.760: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:00:54.760: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:00:54.760: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:00:54.760: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:00:55.760: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:00:55.760: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:00:55.765: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:00:55.765: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:00:56.765: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:00:56.765: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:00:56.765: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:00:56.765: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:00:57.770: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:00:57.770: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:00:57.770: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:00:57.770: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:00:58.770: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:00:58.770: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:00:58.770: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:00:58.770: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:00:59.775: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:00:59.775: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:00:59.775: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:00:59.775: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:00.775: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:00.775: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:00.775: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:00.775: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:01.780: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:01.780: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:01.780: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:01.780: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:02.780: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:02.780: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:02.780: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:02.780: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:03.785: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:03.785: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:03.785: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:03.790: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:04.790: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:04.790: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:04.790: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:04.790: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:05.790: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:05.790: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:05.790: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:05.790: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:06.790: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:06.790: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:06.790: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:06.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:07.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:07.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:07.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:07.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:08.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:08.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:08.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:08.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:09.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:09.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:09.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:09.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:10.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:10.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:10.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:10.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:11.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:11.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:11.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:11.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:12.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:12.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:12.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:12.795: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:13.800: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:13.800: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:13.800: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:13.800: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:14.800: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:14.800: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:14.800: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:14.800: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:15.800: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:15.800: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:15.800: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:15.800: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:16.800: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:16.800: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:16.800: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:16.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:17.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:17.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:17.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:17.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:18.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:18.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:18.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:18.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:19.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:19.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:19.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:19.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:20.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:20.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:20.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:20.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:21.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:21.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:21.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:21.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:22.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:22.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:22.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:22.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:23.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:23.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:23.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:23.805: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:24.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:24.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:24.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:24.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:24.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=200, ext1=703, ext2=224
08-26 12:01:24.810: W/MediaPlayer(4800): info/warning (703, 224)
08-26 12:01:24.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:24.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:24.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=200, ext1=701, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:24.810: W/MediaPlayer(4800): info/warning (701, 0)
08-26 12:01:24.810: I/MediaPlayer(4800): Info (703,224)
08-26 12:01:24.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:24.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:24.810: I/MediaPlayer(4800): Info (701,0)
08-26 12:01:25.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:25.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:25.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:25.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:26.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:26.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:26.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:26.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:27.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:27.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:27.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:27.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:28.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:28.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:28.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:28.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:29.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:29.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:29.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:29.810: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:30.815: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:30.815: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:30.815: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:30.815: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:31.820: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:31.820: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:31.820: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:31.820: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:32.820: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:32.820: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:32.820: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:32.825: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:33.825: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:33.825: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:33.825: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:33.825: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:34.825: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:34.825: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:34.825: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:34.825: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:35.825: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:35.825: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:35.825: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:35.825: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:36.830: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:36.830: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:36.830: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:36.830: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:37.830: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=3, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:37.830: V/MediaPlayer(4800): buffering 0
08-26 12:01:37.830: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:37.830: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:39.170: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=200, ext1=702, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:39.170: W/MediaPlayer(4800): info/warning (702, 0)
08-26 12:01:39.170: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:39.170: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:39.295: I/MediaPlayer(4800): Info (702,0)
08-26 12:01:40.980: V/MediaPlayer(4800): message received msg=2, ext1=0, ext2=0
08-26 12:01:40.980: V/MediaPlayer(4800): playback complete
08-26 12:01:40.980: V/MediaPlayer(4800): callback application
08-26 12:01:40.980: V/MediaPlayer(4800): back from callback
08-26 12:01:49.390: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(4800): stop
08-26 12:01:49.395: V/MediaPlayer(4800): stop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must implement, in your Service, the method onStartCommand.

This method its called by android (don't call it directly). If you implement it and set as return value Service.START_STICKY the Service will stay in 'started' state. Doing this it will be restarted automatically if it gets terminated: it's on the started state so android will call onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) if is mot running.

Anyway Intent data passed to the onStartCommand method will be null if START_STICKY is returned, you should check that.

Code from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29):

```
// This is the old onStart method that will be called on the pre-2.0
// platform.  On 2.0 or later we override onStartCommand() so this
// method will not be called.
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    handleCommand(intent);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handleCommand(intent);
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Returning Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT does the same but the original Intent of the service is redeliver to the onStartCommand method (this way it wouldn't be null)